# Nodejs/Express Passing parameters to ejs view res.render vs window.location.replace

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, parameters, ejs

When passing parameters while using res.render everything works fine:
Html:

```
 <div id="ut_greeting">Welcome:  <%= ut_user %></div>
```

node:

```
 res.render('selection', {ut_user: nickname})
```

However parameter is not passed (returns blank) when I use JavaScript ajax:

```
 window.location.replace("http://localhost:3000/selection?ut_user='" + nickname + "'");
```

Comment: @JudeDesir. No <%= ..%> is on a view html/ejs side. On java script it is as shown or "http://localhost:3000/selection?ut_user=" + nickname ). The result are the same. Blank

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make ut_user a data object of your ut_greeting div as well as a variable rendered by EJS into the div, then just use javascript to get the data variable that was set however you wanted in the ut_greeting div, then pass that back in your window.location.replace line?